# What are the fastest containers available in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, containers

I'm working on a toy/experiment that will require a DNS like service for location/address information of specific nodes on a local network. It will also store other information, such as node type, socket type (enet-udp or tcp), and a few other specific bits of data. most (or possibly all) in numerical types. Each entry will be associated with a specific client by client ID, each client having its own thread within the node.

My question is which boost packages would provide the absolute fastest access by a numerical ID? Though it may never be realized, the idea is that the service may grow to unknown numbers, managing IPC for thousands of clients within threads across multiple nodes.

In other words, the container will have to be fast and be able to grow. If ability to grow leads to a sharp cost in access times than set size container would be preferable, but variable size is ideal. Insert times are not important nor is maintaining order of data within the containers internal structure.

Is boost the wrong place for this type of container/structure? This is the first time that I've had to be extremely picky about structures in boost or even c++ in general, so looking forward to learning something new.

Thanks

Comment: One thread per client?  Sound like a bad idea.  Store state explicitly, and provide threads by capability of the server.  Booking a real thread per ckient means slow context switches, explicit state means you just need to switch state.

Comment: @Yakk - your right, but for now the threads won't be doing anything but talking back.

Comment: If you don't care about performance, then what is the point of your question? Micro optimizations are a bad idea: write it fast and loose if you have a toy, and if you don't have a toy focus on the parts that *matter*, like discarding your one-thread-per-client, rather than "what is the fastest container". The container is going to be a bottleneck way later on, and should be really easy to take out and swap with something faster if you need to: a model where you presume thread based state won't be as easy to swap out.

Comment: @Yakk - I didn't say I don't care about the performance. In fact, I said your right and gave you an up vote. I said the threads won't be doing anything at this point except talking back - ie no state except a connection. The client code that I will merge into this project if it works (which I don't see why it wouldn't) uses boost asio and the threading is handled automatically by a io_service based threadpool. So in short, each 'client' is stored in a session object that is automatically switched as you suggested. This is the standard boost asio pattern.

Comment: @Yakk - I hope I'm not rubbing you the wrong way - I agree with your second comment as well. I just don't think you understood that the client thread is a non issue until I start moving the client code over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just take a moment to make sure that this lookup is in fact going to be one of the bottlenecks of your application (if you're doing I/O any internal lookups will probably be irrelevant).

If you're able to set a cap (max val) on the numeric id and be content with not growing the absolute fastest you can get will be a pre-reserved vector.

Otherwise the most likely candidate is going to be a hash (`unordered_map` from C++11 or boost). The hash will have constant time lookup, but do pay attention to the load factor and when it grows.

Comment: unordered_map ia looking like it will work for what I need. Thanks